# Is it a temporal relationship bad design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, mongoid

So currently I have the following mongoid models.

```
class Delivery
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :address, type: String

  has_many :stops
  belongs_to :current_stop, class_name: 'Stop'

  def next
    current_stop = stops.where(completed: false).first
    save
  end
end

class Stop
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :address, type: String
  field :completed, type: Boolean, default: false

  belongs_to :delivery, inverse_of: :stops
end
```

The general idea is that a delivery has multiple stops where a driver needs to deliver a package, in the Deliver model I keep track of the current stop that is being completed. I used a belongs_to instead of a has_one in the Delivery model because I want to use the generated accessor current_stop_id that is not generated when using has_one. At the other hand I decided not to use a has_one in the Stop model cause I am not going to use it and it can be confusing that when a Stop is being completed it has two relationships pointing to the same Delivery record.

My question is, do you think having this current_stop temporal relationship is bad design considering that it's going to constantly change and at the end when all stops are finished is going to be nil? If so, how would you handle this situation considering that tracking the current stop that is being completed is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how the current stop is used, but your code already has a definition of the current stop:

```
current_stop = stops.where(completed: false).first
```

The `current_stop` method is another way of getting at this information. The two methods can make data out of sync if, say, `current_stop` is updated by multiple threads.

I'd say until you definitely need a cache of the current stop, query `stops` like you are doing whenever you need the current one.